# Dropdowns being chopped off in IE 8 when used with jQuery tmpl plugin

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, drop-down-menu, jquery-templates

I need to show four select lists on a page with the following requirements:

1. The total space allocated to the select lists is fixed (let's say 400 px) i.e. 100 px per select list.
2. The options are much bigger than 100 px. The requirement is to ensure that they should not appear chopped off when the user clicks on the select list to see the options.
3. The solution should work in IE7 and IE8.
4. The 4 select lists will be part of a dynamic template that is being bound using knockoutjs and jquery tmpl plugin.

I was able to get the first 3 requirements going by using the code below (has hard-coded values for the options). When I did so, the select list options were not being chopped off when the user tried to see all the options in IE8.

I was also able to load this template dynamically using jquery tmpl plugin and knockout (requirement 4). However, when I did this, the select options start getting chopped off.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="content" style="width: 400px">
<div id="first" style="width:23%; float:left">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">
        <select>
            <option value="a">This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8</option>
            <option value="b">This is some more random text. </option>
            <option value="c">Still trying to fit in the text.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gapOne" style="width:2%; float:left">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="second" style="width:23%; float:left">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">
        <select>
            <option value="a">This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8</option>
            <option value="b">This is some more random text. </option>
            <option value="c">Still trying to fit in the text.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gapTwo" style="width:2%; float:left">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="third" style="width:23%; float:left">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">
        <select>
                <option value="a">This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8</option>
                <option value="b">This is some more random text. </option>
                <option value="c">Still trying to fit in the text.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="gapThree" style="width:2%; float:left">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">

    </div>
</div>
<div id="fourth" style="width:25%; float:left">
    <div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%">
        <select>
            <option value="a">This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8</option>
            <option value="b">This is some more random text. </option>
            <option value="c">Still trying to fit in the text.</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8
                This is some more random text. 
                Still trying to fit in the text.
            
        
    
    
        

        
    
    
        
            
                This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8
                This is some more random text. 
                Still trying to fit in the text.
            
        
    
    
        

        
    
    
        
            
                This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8
                This is some more random text. 
                Still trying to fit in the text.
            
        
    
    
        

        
    
    
        
            
                This is just a random long line. We are using it to test dropdowns in IE 8
                This is some more random text. 
                Still trying to fit in the text.

Is this code supposed to work with dynamic templates? If not, how can I go about my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

I remember seeing a similar issue in IE before with Knockout. I think a quick solution was to put in the following hack: $("select").width("100px"); (or whatever width you need) after the bindings had been applied. I remember it only affected IE too :-)

Comment: How do I ensure that the bindings are applied. I added the following code based upon your suggestion at the end of the page: $("selectOne").width("98px"); but it didn't work. Here selectOne is the id of the first select element.

Comment: Try $("#selectOne").width("98px"); Do it after your applyBindings call

Comment: Ok, perfect. Now I can see the dropdown options taking the space that I assign in your line of code. Is there any way that we can assign it the space it needs to accomodate the largest value in the options instead of hardcoding it to 98 px or something else. Also, now the dropdown arrow seems to have gone missing.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know a "clean" solution to this problem. I guess you could somehow derive an appropriate width from your longest text value....I don't know your model, but I guess the easiest would be to iterate through your list and find the longest string..I guess you could also pre calculate it in your model ahead of time...

Comment: Thanks so much TGH. I will try to see if I can find anything. Also, would you know why the arrow at the end of the dropdown has gone missing now?

Comment: I am not sure about the arrow... Does it show up if you make the drop down even a little bit wider than 96 px?

Comment: $("#selectOne").width("auto"); makes it expand to the length of the longest option. Now I just need to get the arrows for the dropdowns back. They are being chopped off.

Comment: What happens after you select an entry? Does it appear again then? If so, you could try select the first entry using Jquery after resizing it?

Comment: I noticed that the smaller I keep the width in the code you mentioned, the greater the chance of the arrow coming properly. It works perfectly at 96 px, but is half chopped off at 110 px.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9301/discussion-between-yasir-and-tgh)